# Save a file in json format using Notepad++

Tags: json

I have a json format (let's say text) in Notepad++.

I want to save it as a `json` file using filename.json format.

How can I make it in `Notepad++` (because I can't find the extension when I go to save as option)

Comment: You can save it as .txt and change it manually using a mouse click and your keyboard

Comment: @yiabiten I tried it but when I go to properties it is still txt

Comment: well are you sure you changed the extension ? it is probably filename.json.txt in your case. Are extension displayed by default in your windows ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can save it as .txt and change it manually using a mouse click and your keyboard.
OR, when saving the file:

- choose `All types(*.*)` in the `Save as type` field.
- type filename.json in `File name` field

Comment: This doesn't work without choosing ANSI as encoding when saving

Answer (score 6):

[image]Save the file as `*.txt` and then rename the file and change the file extension to `json`

Comment: Better save your file name with **.json** extension and choose **Save as type** to **All Files**

Answer (score 5):

In Notepad++ on the Language menu you will find the menu item - 'J' and under this menu item chose the language - JSON.

Once you select the JSON language then you won't have to worry about how to save it. When you save it it will by default save it as .JSON file, you have to just select the location of the file.

Thanks,
-Sam

[image: Please look at the pic, it will give you a better idea..]

Answer (score 4):

If you want to save to a specific filename just ignore the provided extensions in Notepad/Word/whatever. Just set the filename.ext in " " and you're done. "Save as type" will be ignored.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just show file name extension from Windows Explorer, after applying the below steps, create a new file, and type your extension as `.json`

Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.

Click the View tab, and then, under Advanced settings, clear the Hide extensions for known file types check box, and then click OK

[Reference](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/show-hide-file-name-extensions#show-hide-file-name-extensions=windows-7)

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can save with extension **.json** but while saving you have to do some changes.

Change **Save as type** in  red circle in image to **All Files**.

It will create .json file with name **bharti.json**.

To check this --> **Right click at file** --> **Properties** --> **Type of file: JSON File (.json)**

[image]

Comment: What's with the huge amount of whitespace at the bottom of the image?

Answer (score 0):

You can do using a simple notepad and save as FILENAME.json

That's all.